# how to insert different citation meta tags for each articles

Tags: joomla-3.4

Depending on the article the name/content will be different, I have tried to add custom tags:

```
<meta name="citation_title" content="The testis isoform of the phosphorylase kinase catalytic subunit (PhK-T)">
<meta name="citation_author" content="Liu, Li" >
<meta name="citation_author" content="Rannels, Sht." >
<meta name="citation_author" content="Falconieri, Mary" >
<meta name="citation_author" content="Phillips, Karen S.">
<meta name="citation_author" content="Wolpert, Ellen B.">
<meta name="citation_author" content="Weaver, Timothy E.">
<meta name="citation_publication_date" content="1996/05/17">
<meta name="citation_journal_title" content="Journal of Biological Chemistry">
<meta name="citation_volume" content="271">
<meta name="citation_issue" content="20">
<meta name="citation_firstpage" content="11761">
<meta name="citation_lastpage" content="11766">
<meta name="citation_pdf_url" content="http://www.example.com/content/271/20/11761.full.pdf">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a plugin, either find a suitable on from JED (e.g. this: http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/tag-meta) or build your own plugin.

Custom tags can also be added with `$document->addCustomTag`.

Example:

```
<?php
  $metatag= '<meta name="citation_title" content="The testis isoform of the phosphorylase kinase catalytic subunit (PhK-T)">' ."\n";
  $metatag.= '<meta name="citation_author" content="Liu, Li" >' ."\n";
  $metatag.= '<meta name="citation_author" content="Rannels, Sht." >' ."\n";
  // add more as needed

  $document = JFactory::getDocument();
  $document->addCustomTag($metatag);
?>
```